# How to write a generic method for UITapGestureRecognizer using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have to add tapGesture for labels and ImageView. How can I create a generic tap gesture method for Labels and ImageView?

```
//TapGestureHandler
extension EditViewController : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{
 //Add Gesture on ImageView
 func addGesture()
 {
    //Gesture Male
    let maleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(maleGestureTap))
    maleTapGesture.delegate = self
    imgViewMale.addGestureRecognizer(maleTapGesture)

    //GestureFemale
    let FemaleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(femaleGestureTap))
    FemaleTapGesture.delegate = self
    imgViewFemale.addGestureRecognizer(FemaleTapGesture)

    //Gesture MaleFemale
    let maleFeTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(maleFeGestureTap))
    maleFeTapGesture.delegate = self
    imgViewMaleFe.addGestureRecognizer(maleFeTapGesture)
 }

 //Tap Gesture Male
 func maleGestureTap()
 {
    imgViewMale.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#CBFFE2")
 }

 //Tap Gesture Female
 func femaleGestureTap()
 {
    imgViewFemale.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#CBFFE2")
 }

 //Tap Gesture MaleFemale
 func maleFeGestureTap()
 {
    imgViewMaleFe.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#CBFFE2")
 }
}
```

I don't know how can we write a generic method.

Comment: why do you not create it for UIView? UILabel and UIImageView extends UIView

Comment: How to create for UIView also?
Thanks

Comment: Please check my updated question.

Comment: you have only one to one relation? (one GestureRecognize for one UIView)

Comment: Actually I have 3 Image view So can't I write a generic tapGesture method for All three ImageView .
I will put conditions inside the tapGesture  method.?

Comment: What actually you what in your UI and what you'r getting right now, please mention in ques so that other can understand the exact problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like that:

Suppose you have a few objects that you need to attach a tap handler to, assuming they all conform to UIView protocol:

```
let subviews: [Any] = [label1, label2, label3, view1, imageview1]()
label1.tag = 1 //** add a tag to your object **
for v in subviews {
   self.addTapGesture(to: v)
}

 func tapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tapped")
    if sender.view?.tag == 1 {
        // *** this is your label1 view ***
    }
}

func addTapGesture(to: Any?) {
    if let v = to as? UIView {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapped(_:)))
        v.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        v.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I will understand and try it.
It would better if can edit it according to my code.
Thanks

Comment: How can I get that info which object will call in tapped Method. Thanks

Comment: a simple way would be to add a tag to your view, see my edits

Comment: If in my another class also having tap gesture methods like for labels and image then how can I create single TapGestureMethod for all Classes?

Comment: @kishor0011 I'm not sure what you mean.. what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Define your target `selector(tapGestureHandler:)` with argument as

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tapGestureHandler:"))
```

And check your component like this.

```
func tapGestureHandler(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

     if sender.view is UIView {
     // sender is a UIView 
     }
     else if sender.view is UIImageView{
    // sender is UIimageView
     }
     else{
     // sender is none
     }
}
```

And be ensure that `user interaction is true`.

Comment: It's in Objective -C 
and  I know swift only.
thanks

Comment: @kishor0011 check again

Comment: Cast from 'UITapGestureRecognizer' to unrelated type 'UIView' always fails. 

Warning

Comment: @kishor0011 check once again